# Change Title Of Geoserver Legend Decoration

Tags: geoserver, sld, layouts

My colorramp legend's title gets set to be the layer's name. I'm wondering if I can override this and set the title explicitly. For example let's say I want to change the colorramp's title from "Spring Index, Daily Anomaly - Leaf Anomaly" to just "Leaf Anomaly".

Currently This is the WMS result I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see it's getting "Spring Index, Daily Anomaly - Leaf Anomaly" from the layer title:

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<layout>
  <decoration type="text" affinity="bottom,left" offset="26,20">
    <option name="message" value="Difference from average in the timing of the Start of Spring, as estimated through an index of early-leafing plants"/>
    <option name="font-size" value="15"/>
    <option name="font-bold" value="true"/>
    <option name="font-family" value="Arial"/>
    <option name="halo-radius" value="4"/>
  </decoration>
  <decoration type="text" affinity="bottom,left" offset="26,0">
    <option name="message" value="Results Provisional  (www.usanpn.org/data/spring)"/>
    <option name="font-size" value="15"/>
    <option name="font-italic" value="true"/>
    <option name="font-family" value="Arial"/>
    <option name="halo-radius" value="4"/>
  </decoration>
  <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,right" offset="4,-55" size="auto"/>
</layout>
```

Here is my colorramp sld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>days</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>days</Name>
      <Title>Days Difference</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ColorMap>         
              <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="-9999" label="Day Difference" opacity="0.0"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#67001f" quantity="-20"   label="20 Days Early"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#b2182b" quantity="-8"    label="8 Days Early"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#d6604d" quantity="-6"    label="6 Days Early"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#f4a582" quantity="-4"    label="4 Days Early"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fddbc7" quantity="-2"    label="2 Days Early"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#f7f7f7" quantity="0"     label="No Difference"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#d1e5f0" quantity="2"     label="2 Days Later"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#92c5de" quantity="4"     label="4 Days Late"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#4393c3" quantity="6"     label="6 Days Late"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#2166ac" quantity="8"     label="8 Days Late"/>
              <ColorMapEntry color="#053061" quantity="20"    label="20 Days Later"/>
            </ColorMap>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer by digging into the LegendDecoration source found here: https://fossies.org/dox/geoserver-2.8.2/LegendDecoration_8java_source.html

The solution is to set the sldTitle option to "true" like so:

```
<decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,right" offset="4,-55" size="auto">
    <option name="sldTitle" value="true"/>
  </decoration>
```

Then the title will come from the title attribute in your style sld (in my case it changed the title to "Days Difference" as per the below sld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>days</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>days</Name>
      <Title>Days Difference</Title>
```

If sldTitle is not set, Geoserver pulls the title from the layer title.