# Change SLD file to add title

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a SLD file generated from QGIS and added to GeoServer. My SLD is just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" version="1.0.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <UserLayer>
    <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
      <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
    </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>pejao_dtm_1m_4326</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
            <sld:ChannelSelection>
              <sld:GrayChannel>
                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
              </sld:GrayChannel>
            </sld:ChannelSelection>
            <sld:ColorMap type="ramp">
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="74.821899400000007" label="74.8219" color="#440154"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="107.863498675" label="107.8635" color="#3b528b"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="140.90509795" label="140.9051" color="#21908d"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="173.94669722499998" label="173.9467" color="#5dc963"/>
              <sld:ColorMapEntry quantity="206.98829649999999" label="206.9883" color="#fde725"/>
            </sld:ColorMap>
          </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I try to add `<sld:Title>pejao</sld:Title>` expecting to have a title in the legend. The validation returned not errors; however, it doesn't work. Any ideas on how to add a title to my legend from GeoServer?

Comment: where did you add the `title`? how are you generating the legend?

Comment: I add after <sld:Name>pejao_dtm_1m_4326</sld:Name>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Title Of Geoserver Legend Decoration](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186535/change-title-of-geoserver-legend-decoration)

Comment: In that example, I see that there is already a title in the sld and also the structure of the sld is very different from mine.

Comment: how are you fetching the legend?

Comment: I am using QGIS to assign a legend to the raster file. Then I save the legend as SLD format and open in GeoServer.

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I still do not find a solution.